# Unable to migrate spring-security pointcut from SpringBoot 1x to 2x

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm migrating a `1.5 SpringBoot` app to `SpringBoot 2.1.6` and the app fails to start during the `AutoConfiguration`.

My *SpringBootApplication* has a `@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath:security.xml"})` that has a pointcut on all my Service classes in order to add a fake role on all methods to deny access to them so the developer is forced to add a `@PreAuthorize` with a real role.

When I remove the `protect-pointcut` part from the **`security.xml`**, everything works well.

With `Spring 1.5` everything works well.

I assume that there is a problem in the order of executions (*autocofigure + adding pointcuts*)

Maybe protecting all service methodsusing a pointcuts in security.xml in order to force developers to add a PreAuthorize annotations is not the right way to do that in SpringBoot 2?

**The Main**

```java
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath:security.xml"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

**The security.xml**

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
            xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* my.service.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_TO_OVERRIDE"/>
    </global-method-security>

    <beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

**The application.properties**

```
server.port=8484
server.tomcat.basedir=
server.servlet.context-path=/
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.flyway.enabled=false
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
```

**The pom**

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<!--                        <version>1.5.19.RELEASE</version>-->
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$380a5a20]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/metadata/DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine superclass of missing type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration$$Lambda$406.629078509
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at jdm.Main.main(Main.java:31) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$380a5a20]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/metadata/DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine superclass of missing type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration$$Lambda$406.629078509
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:300) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/metadata/DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine superclass of missing type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration$$Lambda$406.629078509
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1467) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1322) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1209) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1883) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$380a5a20.() ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException: warning can't determine superclass of missing type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration$$Lambda$406.629078509
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ExceptionBasedMessageHandler.handleMessage(ReflectionWorld.java:219) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Lint$Kind.signal(Lint.java:340) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.raiseCantFindType(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:237) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.getSuperclass(MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature.java:98) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.addSignaturesUpToFirstDefiningMember(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:95) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:49) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.MemberImpl.getJoinPointSignatures(MemberImpl.java:515) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern.matches(SignaturePattern.java:319) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut.matchInternal(KindedPointcut.java:202) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.getShadowMatch(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:319) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:129) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesMethodExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:110) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.method.ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.attemptMatch(ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.java:142) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.method.ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ProtectPointcutPostProcessor.java:125) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

Comment: One of the changes in Spring Boot 2.x is that the default connection pool implementation is now Hikari instead of Tomcat DBCP. I see some references to Hikari in the many failed bean messages. You could try to force DBCP to still be used to see if that makes any difference. If it does, at least that has narrowed it down a little bit. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#configuring-a-datasource

Comment: I already tried removing the whole database autoconfiguration, I also tried to force Tomcat. The application still fails unless I remove the pointcut part from the xml.